# Can't seem to figure out this binary operation question

Tags: inverse, binary

On the set  {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9},  I define the operation ⊗ to be like our standard multiplication, except that the result is just the last digit of the product.  For example,  4 ⊗ 7 = 8,  since  4 × 7 = 28,  and 8 is the last digit of 28.  Noticing that 1 is the identity element for ⊗, find the inverse of each element of the set with respect to ⊗ (or if an element doesn’t have an inverse, explain how you know it doesn't)

Comment: Hint: if $a+b=10$ then $a\oplus b=0$.

Comment: well $a \oplus ??? = 0$.

Comment: Thanks guys, I realize that.. Just unsure what the inverse of the example in the question would be..

Comment: You can't figure out what $a + ??? = 10$ is?

Comment: No, I can figure that out, I just don't how the operation required to get the inverse of lets say, 7.

Comment: with the identity element being 0, I would need to get -7 in order to reach the 0 identity property. I am really confused this problem is just puzzling me

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: You don't know what $7 + ??? = 10$ is?????  C'mon man!  Think!  You most certain *must* know what $7 + x =10$ therefore $x = ????$.

Comment: 3 lol, I'm sorry there was a slight miscommunication.. I am just really lost in this question.. Could you give me an example of how you would find the inverse of lets say.. 5 on this set?

Comment: @MikeNittiIV if 7+3=10 -> 0, the 3 is the inverse of 7

Comment: OHHHH! I totally understand now, since the identity is 0, you essentially only need to find what number adds to 10, and only take the second digit,(0) to achieve the identity (0)

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I'm going to work this one out and get back to you.

Comment: So, if im not mistaken.. the inverses for the set should be as follows...

Comment: 0=10, 1=9,2=8,3=7,4=6,5=5,6=4,7=3,8=2,9=1,10=0?

Comment: You got it!  It comes together eventually.

Comment: Okay, thanks again. I have another problem similar to the first, only with multiplication.. Im going to try it on my own, but if i cant figure it out I may post the problem on this thread.

Comment: Ooops  you are 9/11 correct on your inverses. 10 isn't in the set so 10 doesn't have an inverse.  and the inverse of 0 is not 10.  As $0 \oplus 0 = 0$ the inverse of $0$ is $0$.  That's actually true for an addition you define.

Comment: This is the next problem, so far the only numbers in this set I can think of that have an inverse with the identity being 1 are 1, 3 and 7

Comment: @MikeNittiIV The second problem, which you talked, corresponds to "ring" theory, which I first posted. elements 1,3,7and 9 have inverses with 1 as multiplicative identity.

Comment: Wouldnt 9 have an inverse as well? 81.. what would the inverse for 5 be?

Answer (score 4):

As you notice $0$ is the identity.  $0 \oplus a = a \oplus 0 = a$.

Notice that if $a, b \ne 0$ then $0 < a + b \le 18 < 20$ so if $a \oplus b =0$ then $a + b = 10$.

So $b = 10 -a$.

So that's the inverse....

$a^{inverse} = 10 - a$.   And $a \oplus a^{inverse} =  a \oplus (10 - a) = [10] = 0$.

Comment: I'd denote the $\oplus$ inverse as ${^\ominus a}$ or such; but that's just style choice.

Comment: Hmm, good point and I was concerned about that.  I wasn't sure which notation the op would be comfortable so I defaulted to $a^{-1}$ although I really don't usually like to use that for *additive* inverses.

Answer (score 0):

The operation you are specifying is equivalent to addition modulo 10. The corresponding inverses are just $(10-the \space number)$. The set with the given operation forms the group $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$. Here, the $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ corresponds to the group of integers with respect to the operation of addition modulo 10. Therefore, every element has an inverse.

Comment: Um.. If it's a *group* (not a ring) all elements have *additive* inverses.  The OP never said anything about a multiplication operation.

Comment: @fleablood thanks, I have made the necessary edits.

Comment: I think you are assuming a lot more experience with group theory than the OP has at this point.  I imagine the OP has only been introduced to the concept last week or so.

Comment: @fleablood nevertheless, i think the answer may atleast introduce the OP to the general class of such problems  and even to modular arithmetic

Comment: Agreed.  I did wonder whether to point out $a \oplus b = a+b $ with first digits knocked of is the same as $a + b = k + 10*n$ but decided s/he'll find out soon enough.